# Database snapshot performance considerations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a very big stored procedure that is timing out.

That procedure updates around 15 different tables.
It also read data from different databases in the same server.

I would like to reproduce the environment, without changing anything (update/insert data in any table).

Is it OK to create a snapshot of the original database and do all my tests there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A database snapshot is read only so the procedure will not be able to do anything. To repro the problem ask the database administrator of the system to give you a backup of the database. Restore this backup on your dev/test environment and analyze the problem there. As your proc reads from multiple DBs, you'll also need a backup of *those*. Ideally the dev/test environment would have identical hardware characteristics (same CPU/cache/Memory/disk), but this is often impossible.

Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) to understand what you have to look at after you get your repro environment. Make sure you solve the actual problem, not a problem that occurs *only* on your repro environment because of hardware diffs.

As a side note, an enormous amount of information can be collected non-invasively from the production server just via adequate monitoring. Again, read the article linked.